# Storing lines into array and print line by line

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, readlines

Current code:

```
filepath = "C:/Bg_Log/KLBG04.txt"
with open(filepath) as fp:
    lines = fp.read().splitlines()
    with open(filepath, "w") as fp:
        for line in lines:
            print("KLBG04",line,line[18], file=fp)
```

output:

```
KLBG04 20/01/03 08:09:13 G0001 G
```

Require flexibility to move the columns around and also manipulate the date as shown below with array or list

```
KLBG04 03/01/20 G0001 G 08:09:13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide sample data, but I think this may work:

```
filepath = "C:/Bg_Log/KLBG04.txt"
with open(filepath) as fp:
    lines = fp.read().splitlines()
    with open(filepath, "w") as fp:
        for line in lines:
            ln = "KLBG04 " + line + " " + line[18]  # current column order
            sp = ln.split()  # split at spaces
            dt = '/'.join(sp[1].split('/')[::-1])  # reverse date
            print(sp[0],dt,sp[3],sp[-1],sp[-2]) # new column order
            # print("KLBG04",line,line[18], file=fp)
```

Comment: Thank you @mike67. The code works perfectly for me however I can't comment much as I new to programming

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store the output as a string itself and use the `split()` method to split the string at each space and then use another split method for the index 1 (The index that will contain the date) and split it again at each `/` (So that you can then manipulate the date around).

```py
for line in lines:
        String output ="KLBG04",line,line[18], file=fp   # Rather than printing store the output in a string #
x = output.split(" ")
date_output = x[1].split("/")
# Now you can just manipulate the data around and print how you want to #
```

Comment: I would suggest that whenever you are dealing with time, use a date and time manipulating module such as `datetime` for a cleaner and more understandable code.

Comment: Yeah that'll be a better way to do this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to `split()` the line first, then print the list in your desired order

```
from datetime import datetime # use the datetime module to manipulate the date

filepath = "C:/Bg_Log/KLBG04.txt"
with open(filepath) as fp:
    lines = fp.read().splitlines()
    with open(filepath, "w") as fp:
        for line in lines:
            date, time, venue = line.split(" ") # split the line up
            date = datetime.strptime(date, '%y/%m/%d').strftime('%d/%m/%y') # format your date
            print("KLBG04", date, venue, venue[0], time, file=fp) # print in your desired order
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`

```
for line in lines:
    words = line.split()  # split every word
    date_values = words[0].split('/') # split the word that contains date
    
    #create a dictionary as follows
    date_format = ['YY','DD','MM']
    date_dict = dict(zip(date_format, date_values))
    
    #now create a new variable with changed format
    new_date_format = date_dict['MM'] + '/' + date_dict['DD'] + '/' + date_dict['YY']
    print(new_date_format)
    
    #replace the first word [index 0 is having date] with new date format
    words[0] = new_date_format
    
    #join all the words to form a new line
    new_line = ' '.join(words)
    print("KLBG04",new_line,line[18])
```

`